# Finding whether a sum of numbers in a set generate another number

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, computer-science

I have a set of numbers $\{a_1,\dots,a_n\}$ and another number $k$. I need to find whether sum of any combination of numbers in the set produces $k$. It can be $a_1 + a_2$ or $a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + a_7$. I don't want the actual numbers itself but just a yes or no answer on whether possible or not. Is there any efficient algorithm other than the brute force one to check each permutation?

Comment: This problem is known as the subset sum problem.  In general it is hard (NP-complete).  Here is a Wikipedia link for more info http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem

Comment: Once again we see that math is like magic: once you know the true name of something (in this case, "subset sum problem") you can control it.

Comment: For low values of the parameters a_i and k, a CAS can easily solve for the coefficient c_k of x^k in $\prod _{i=1}^n \left(x^{a_i}+1\right)$, where c_k counts the different ways to obtain k as a subset-sum.